# Zend Form can't use action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

My action helper just echos "ok" when called

```
class Helper_MyActionHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
   public function direct(){
      echo "ok";
   }
}
```

When I test it in my controller, it works fine and echos ok.

```
$this->_helper->myActionHelper();
```

But when I do the same thing in a form, it doesn't work at all. I tried

```
$this->_helper->myActionHelper();
$this->_helper->myActionHelper;
```

So can I use an action helper in a form.. is there a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
$helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('MyActionHelper');
echo $helper->direct();
```

Look at The Helper Broker section in the documentation : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Answer (score 3):

A more accurate name for Action Helpers would be Action-Controller helpers.  They're meant to be called from action controller methods.  You cannot, out of the box, call them from other Zend objects.

Answer (score 3):

Action Helpers are not designed to 'help' non-action elements of your application.

Your `$form` has no concept of registered action helpers (`$this->_helper`) or even the context in which the helpers are configured.

You can read up here and learn where plugins work within the Zend Framework lifecycle:
http://www.eschrade.com/page/zend-framework-request-lifecycle-4b9a4288

If you revise your question and let us know what you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to suggest alternative methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could always pass the myActionHelper object to the form as a paramater.